how to configure binding in Extjs
Morning,
I'm trying to understand binding in Extjs, so I am looking for a good article.
The more I read all the questions, the more it confuses me.
Can anyone point me to a good article?
Arno.

This will provide you with a strong foundation in data binding concepts. In this article, you'll learn how data binding works and some of the useful techniques it allows.
https://www.sencha.com/blog/data-binding-in-the-ext-js-modern-toolkit/
